# Laravel 5.4 : count the products in each category and sort them by Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two `Models` one is `Product` and the other is `ProductCategory`

and I have relations between both

Product Model

```
public function productCategory() {
        return $this->belongsTo( ProductCategory::class, 'product_category_id' );
    }
```

Product Category Model

```
public function categoryProduct() {
        return $this->hasMany( Product::class, 'product_category_id' );
    }
```

now each category has some product like `(cat-1 has 3 products, cat-2 has 7 products, cat-3 has 5 products)`.

I need an `Eloquent query` which will get 4 categories sorted by the count of products in each category.

For Ex.

```
cat-2 has 7 products
cat-3 has 5 products
cat-1 has 3 products
```

tahnks

Comment: For the other (now deleted question), see **https://regex101.com/r/YlH0lh/3/** which accepts the same formats but is shorter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) and then [orderBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) to make it with `single` query.

```
ProductCategory::with('categoryProduct')->withCount('categoryProduct')->orderBy('category_product_count','desc')->get();
```

To get just the count

```
ProductCategory::withCount('categoryProduct')->orderBy('category_product_count','desc')->get();
```

Comment: is that possible to make a sort for another column name?
Like sort on created_at, title, name, etc.

Comment: on another table or same table? if you want to sort by column of another table then better use JOIN, for same table just change the name on orderBy clause

Answer (score 1):

Then you can try it as:

```
$rows= ProductCategory::withCount('categoryProduct')->get();
```

and you can access this by:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
echo $row->categoryProduct_count;
}
```

this is pure eloquent

Answer (score 0):

suppose you get the `$categories` as a collection then you can define a custom sort by function

```
    $categories = ProductCategory::all()->with('categoryProduct'); //which will fetch you all categories with products

    $sorted = $categories->sortBy(function ($category, $key) {
        return count($category);
    });
```

[doc link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sort)